# MacBook Pro 13” 2014 - Trackpad gestures not working after long sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, gesture

I haven’t used my MacBook for around 2 weeks, it’s been in sleep mode (closed lid).

I’ve never had any issues with my MacBook Pro, but suddenly any form of gesture other than 1 finger on the trackpad causes a temporary 2/3 second freeze. Here’s what I’ve tried:

- killall Dock on the console
- updated to High sierra OS
- unticked all trackpad gesture options
- reset the SMC
- sleeping, restarting, powering off and on

I’ve had absolutely no luck, not even temporary. It’s literally the moment it senses an additional finger on the pad that it freezes.

As there were no physical or software changes between when it worked and when it didn’t, can I assume it’s something to do with the long sleep? Are there any further tips for potential solutions or has anyone experienced this specific problem?

Answer (score 2):

I've recently had this issue as well. I found the temporary solution to be related to the `hidd` process. If you head to Activity Monitor and forcibly terminate the process (as outlined in the fifth option in [this article from OSXDaily](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/02/force-quit-mac-apps/)), the gestures should return.